SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'port' occur when execute "docker-compose up" command in command prompt
When I execute "docker-compose up", there is an error related to Javascript about node. Here is Javascript file
index.js
const express = require('express');
redis =require('redis');

const app = express();
const client = redis.createClient({
   host: 'redis-server',
   port: 6379
});
client.set('visitor', 0);

app.get('/', (req, res)  => {
    client.get('visitor', (err, visitor) => {
        res.send('Number of visitor is '+ visitor);
        client.set('visitor', parseInt(visitor) + 1);
    });
});

app.listen(8081, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port 8081');
});

Here is the result when execute "docker-compose up"
C:\Users\pvdat\visitor>docker-compose up
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                                  docker:default
[+] Running 2/0
 ✔ Container visitor-redis-server-1  Created                                                                                                                       0.0s
 ✔ Container visitor-node-app-1      Created                                                                                                                       0.0s
Attaching to visitor-node-app-1, visitor-redis-server-1
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:C 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.664 # WARNING Memory overcommit must be enabled! Without it, a background save or replication may fail under low memory condition. Being disabled, it can also cause failures without low memory condition, see https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1328. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:C 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.667 * oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:C 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.667 * Redis version=7.2.3, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:C 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.667 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.668 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.679 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.681 * Server initialized
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.681 * Loading RDB produced by version 7.2.3
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.682 * RDB age 7 seconds
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.682 * RDB memory usage when created 0.83 Mb
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.682 * Done loading RDB, keys loaded: 0, keys expired: 0.
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.683 * DB loaded from disk: 0.001 seconds
visitor-redis-server-1  | 1:M 17 Jul 2024 17:37:59.683 * Ready to accept connections tcp
visitor-node-app-1      |
visitor-node-app-1      | > start
visitor-node-app-1      | > node index.js
visitor-node-app-1      |
visitor-node-app-1      | /app/index.js:7
visitor-node-app-1      |     port: 6379
visitor-node-app-1      |     ^^^^
visitor-node-app-1      |
visitor-node-app-1      | SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'port'
visitor-node-app-1      |     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:18)
visitor-node-app-1      |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1405:20)
visitor-node-app-1      |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1544:10)
visitor-node-app-1      |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:32)
visitor-node-app-1      |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:12)
visitor-node-app-1      |     at wrapModuleLoad (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:212:19)
visitor-node-app-1      |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:158:5)
visitor-node-app-1      |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:30:49
visitor-node-app-1      |
visitor-node-app-1      | Node.js v22.3.0
visitor-node-app-1 exited with code 1  


Are you sure you have the comma after host: 'redis-server'? You'll get that error if the comma is missing.

Yes Barmar, of course. As you can see                                                                                            host: 'redis-server',
port: 6379

You wouldn't be the first person to post code different from what they're actually running, so I don't trust what I can "see".

Make sure you actually deployed it this way. I can't see any other reason for that error, the code you posted looks fine.

Sorry, I'm just new and don't know how to share a good question. But I already put comma
